# Magmi - importing html description

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.7, magmi

I am using magmi datapump *(Magmi version 0.7.18)* to import products into Magento 1.7 from an xml feed, and I have a problem with product descriptions. The product descriptions in the xml feed contain html tags (example below)

```
     <div>
       <span style="font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt;">
            Design-ul carcasei Procell      <strong>TPU Dual Bubbles</strong> este gandit atat pentru aspect, cat si pentru protectia impotriva loviturilor puternice. Canalele circulare din interiorul carcasei preiau socul loviturii, protejand astfel spatele iPhone-ului cu eficienta </span>
</div>
```

The relevant line for the description in my import script is:

```
'description' => base64_decode($record->Descriere)), // decodes the full description from xml feed
```

When I run the import script, the product descriptions are correctly imported into Magento and show up in the product description field (with html tags).

However, on the frontend the html tags are not parsed, so the description shows up with html tags. I have checked the description attribute and both Allow Html tags on fronted and Enable **WYSIWYG** are enabled. I've also checked the template files and the htmlspecialchars function is removed from the product description. Also tried reindexing and flushing / manually deleting cache, it doesn't work.

The weird thing is that if I edit a product in the admin interface and save it manually, the html in the description renders correctly on the frontend, but I can't manually save every product. I've checked the database values for the description attribute on a product before and after saving manually and there were no changes.

Furthermore, I've imported the same html descriptions with Magento Dataflow and the html renders correctly on the frontend (without needing to save the product manually), so I guess there is a problem with the way Magmi handles html in descriptions, or there is a bug in Magento.

I've also tested on Magento 1.8 and the behaviour is the same.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you viewing the descriptions in the Magento backend with the WYSIWYG editor?  If so, view click hide the WYSIWYG editor and view the raw output of the description.  Are tags appearing like this: `&lt;span&gt;`?  Check the database directly and see if the HTML tags are being converted into HTML entity values.

Comment: If I hide the editor the tags show up like this <li><ul> etc. I've also checked the database, the html tags appear in the same way.

Comment: FYI this is still happening with simple CSV import into Magento 2.3.1